# Multiple fork() in switch lead to exponential exec

Tags: c, switch-statement, fork

I have a program which executes multiple programs depending on i. See the following code block:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 switch(i){
  case 0:
    if(fork())result=execl(transportProtoSnd,transportProtoSnd,RTPport, NULL);
    if(result<0){printf("ERRNO: %d\n", errno);exit(0);}
    break;
 case 1:
    if(fork())result=execl(fecSnd,fecSnd,RTPport-1, nameOfTransportProto, NULL);
    if(result<0){printf("ERRNO: %d\n", errno);exit(0);}
    break;
 case 2:
    if(fork())result=execl(fecRcv,fecRcv,RTPport-2, nameOfTransportProto, NULL);
    if(result<0){printf("ERRNO: %d\n", errno);exit(0);}
    break;
 case 3:
    if(fork())result=execl(transportProtoRcv,transportProtoRcv, RTPport-3, NULL);
    if(result<0){printf("ERRNO: %d\n", errno);exit(0);}
    break;
 }
}
```

The problem is that the process tree looks like:

```
0:00  \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly
```

By using vfork() i get a better behaviour:

```
0:00  \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |   \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |       \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |           \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly 
0:00  |               \_ NfqCallTracking/NfqCallTracking 0 Tests/NfqVerdictOnly
```

But actually it should look like:

```
0:00 udevd --daemon
0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
```

IIRC vfork() does not use the state of the parent process. Thus i prevent the exponential forking in ps tree 1. However using vfork each child evolves of the parent child, see tree 2. In my opinion by using fork() or vfork() the tree should look like the ps tree 3.

Kind Regards

Comment: What's with the for-switch? A complex and pointless way to write straight-line code.

Comment: If you remove all lines starting with `for`, `switch`, `case` and `break`, your code will still be exactly equivalent to the original. There's no point in going around a loop only to execute completely different code in each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, here's what is happening.

```
if(fork())result=execl(transportProtoSnd,transportProtoSnd,RTPport, NULL);
if(result<0){printf("ERRNO: %d\n", errno);exit(0);}
```

The parent forks and **immediately execs** (and never returns of course). That's what that `if` does. Then **the child** tests a bogus result value, and goes on to spawn another program (i++).

So the main problem seems to be that you are execing in the parent instead of the child (which  is pretty weird). You should be doing something like:

```
if(fork() == 0) {
    execl(transportProtoSnd,transportProtoSnd,RTPport, NULL);
    /* If it reaches this handle error. */
}
```

Obviously you should be checking the return code of `fork(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

From the man-page of 'fork':

> On  success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.

Which mean for your program the the parent-process execls and the child-process continues the loop to fork the others... thus the tree, IMHO. Try to inverse the if-condition.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the other answers, you should be aware that you create zombies this way - at least if you have a long-running "parent" program. You should note the PID of the `fork()`ed processes, maybe in an array, and do a `wait()`, `waitid()` or `waitpid()`.